# Intersecting meshes

Tags: mesh

I have a model with 2 separate objects that intersects each other. My question is, is it advisable to left it in such condition? Can i just leave them like that? Or do i have to merge them into one using ctrl+j? And if i merge them, do i have to connect the intersection using faces, or i can just leave them without connecting? Can i leave faces which are inside object, eg. if you intersect cylinder on its axis into the cube?

This might be important as i want to texture the model in external program, and then i might port it into other 3d modeler or into game engine.

Sorry for the trivial questions but i haven't found answer. Im newbie to the whole 3d modelling and game design.

Comment: There is no right answer to this question, it all depends on a lot of factors. You are going to have to make this decision yourself, in different situations texturing separate objects is better in other, it is better to have them all one mesh

Comment: AFAIK i see downside already to leaving the objects intersected with each other. You have unnecessary parts in UV texture that won't be even visible, so there's no point of giving them a texture. How would game engine eg. unity or UE treat the model that have several separate meshes that are not merged into one object? Can it even work? How it can know which one to select for transformation? These questions might be answered by reference/manual for engines, but i would just like to hear a quick answer.

Comment: I guess in 3dcoat or substance painter i can just paint the visible part of the model, so no time wasted for texturing the non-visible parts?